# Send email through procedure in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to make a procedure through which  I can send email to my team mail id.
actually there are number of procedures running daily in our system.So i want to send the status of each procedure means if procedure is getting success,failed or running.If the procedure is in running state i have to show the running time in that email.And also if the procedure is failed then i have to show the error message in that email.Actually one table is present in our database in which procedure

```
id,date,start_time,end_time,status,error
```

desc columns are there.I shared the details below.

```
proc id   date        start_time               end_time                status       error desc
  1      6/7/2017    7/5/2017 9:55:16 AM     7/6/2017 1:36:25 AM      SUCCESS   
  2      6/28/2017   6/29/2017 8:30:02 AM    6/29/2017 2:20:15 PM     FAIL         -1555 - ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 334 with name "_SYSSMU334_1817651691$" too small
ORA-02063:
  3      7/5/2017    7/6/2017 9:34:54 AM                              RUNNING
```

As i said i have to show all the 3 types of status in the email which is to be sent through procedure.kindly help me regarding this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sent email in Oracle PL/SQL package to multiple receivers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732220/how-to-sent-email-in-oracle-pl-sql-package-to-multiple-receivers)

Comment: please read "How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?"
https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting
makes it easier to understand your question - thx in advance

Comment: But how to send that status of the procedure.I did not get.Can you please clarify me my issue  once again ?Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? You have specified a number of requirements in your question but you haven't described exactly what problem you are having.