# ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.7.0 authentication required

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g

Please help me, I'm trying to send mail from Oracle database 11g and while sending the mail from database, I'm getting the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXPHG.png)

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail_deepak_test (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_subject   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);

  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```

Comment: Ask your administrator to gran you the required permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is very clear. Authenticate:

```
base64username := UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('a@b.com')));  
base64password := UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('1234')));

con:= UTL_SMTP.open_connection('myhost', 25);
UTL_SMTP.ehlo(con, smtpHost);
UTL_SMTP.command(con, 'AUTH', 'LOGIN');
UTL_SMTP.command(con, base64username );
UTL_SMTP.command(con, base64password );
```

Another solution is - like @FDavidoc mentioned - to ask your Admin to lower the security for your machine and allow sending mails without Auth. This way you don't have to worry about passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your p_to variable consists of more than one email recipient.
I have got this error for this cause.
if you want to send multiple recipients: You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732220/how-to-sent-email-in-oracle-pl-sql-package-to-multiple-receivers) answer.