# How to send a message to multiple recipients

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, oracle10g

I've tried to send a message to a single recipient by using

```
UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);
```

where p_to can contain only a email address. In order to send a message to multiple recipients, the only possibility (as far as I know) is to call this routine multiple times, but is there another way to send the same message to multiple recipients all at once so as to allow every recipient to see the others instead of having multiple emails ?

Oracle version 10g

Thanks

Mark

Comment: [Related question?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17732220/266304) "call this routine multiple times" means call `utl_smtp.rcpt` multiple times, not the entire email-sending routine.

Comment: [`utl_mail.send`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_MAIL.html#GUID-47AE34E9-3123-4115-AC86-4FF538DBFBBB) accepts a comma-separated list of recipients. It's not installed by default though, and it has one or two other restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it is one-by-one. However, you don't have to send "n" mails, just call `UTL_SMPT.RCPT` as many times as needed.

For example, in my procedure, I'm passing separate parameters for To, Cc and Bcc and then concatenate them into a single local  variable (they should be split by semi-colon):

```
l_recipients :=
        par_to
     || CASE WHEN par_cc IS NOT NULL THEN ';' || par_cc END
     || CASE WHEN par_bcc IS NOT NULL THEN ';' || par_bcc END;
```

and then - in a loop - calling the `RCPT` procedure for each recipient:

```
  FOR cur_r IN (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_recipients,
                                          '[^;]+',
                                          1,
                                          LEVEL) recipient
                      FROM DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (l_recipients, ';') + 1)
  LOOP
     UTL_SMTP.rcpt (l_smtp_connection, cur_r.recipient);
  END LOOP;
```

(Note that this is 11g example; 10g - you use - doesn't have `REGEXP_COUNT` function, but that's not the main issue here).

Later, I'm just *saying* who is who as

```
  -- From / To / Cc / Bcc
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_smtp_connection,
                       'From: ' || par_sender || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_smtp_connection,
                       'To: '   || par_to     || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_smtp_connection,
                       'Cc: '   || par_cc     || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_smtp_connection,
                       'BCc: '  || par_bcc    || UTL_TCP.crlf);
```