# How to send multiple people the mail using UTL_SMTP

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-20.2, oracle-apex-20.1

I have been trying so hard but not able to implement

Any solution is great appreciated !!!

I am using `APEX 20.x`

I Built one form which as following content in it : `textfiled , textarea , choosfile , button`

```
FROM EMAIL : TextFiled1      
SUBJECT    : TextFiled2  
NOTES      : TextArea1
ATTACHMENT : choosefile1 
SUBMIT
```

**Database records in table :** `EMPLOYEE`

```
ID,NAME,AGE,EMAIL,STATUS
11,ALICE,12,abc@protonmail.com,Y
32,BOB,32,acd@protonmail.com,N
45,RAY,22,xyz@protonmail.com,Y
36,TIN,24,tin@protonmail.com,Y
```

**My code :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_subject   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_attachment IN BLOB,   
                                       p_notes       IN CLOB,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);
  
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```

**What I am trying to implement :**

I need to iterate through my table `EMPLOYEE` and read one by one email id's and send email to them.

Need to write some for loop to iterate the employee table ?  and shoot mail to them with details entered in components along with that if attachment if choosen [optional]    :  `SUBJECT  , NOTES  , ATTACHMENT`

I have 700+ email ids

Need to send all of them same details over their mail one by one reading from table `EMPLOYEE`

Comment: Do you mean sending individual emails to multiple people; or sending [the same email to multiple recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17735362/266304)? Which is mostly about where you put the loop, but also whether the recipients see each other (to/CC vs BCC).

Comment: @AlexPoole : Sending same mail to multiple users. Why I want to  loop one one record and send mail on button click because outlook does not allow bulk mail sending in one go 100 to 200 . Maximum is only at a time 100